# How do I use a wireless shutter release?

Tags: shutter, wireless, shutter-release

I just bought a wireless shutter release and came with instructions that are so brief as to make them not helpful at all.  Can anyone write something with detailed instructions how to use this?  Should the camera set to B mode, or can it be set to AV, TV or M mode?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what brand and model your wireless unit is as well as your camera. You could link to both if that is possible.

Comment: Yes model of wireless shutter would be very helpful. Is it IR or radio? does it have a bit to attach to the camera etc? we won't know until you tell us

Answer (score 6):

**You normally have to set the camera to accept the remote signal.** This can be found sometimes with the drive modes or self-timer, it really depends on your model.

Once the camera is ready. **Aim at one of the IR receptors and click the release.** Some cameras have a front receptor, some have a back one and some have both. Look for what looks like a small very dark window.

The camera can be in any mode and it will take the shot accordingly. Most models will not autofocus when used with the remote, some will let you specify this as an custom setting.

Bulb mode either works by holding the release the whole time (which IMO is silly) or by clicking at the beginning and end of the internal. A few DSLRs allow both and the behavior is chosen via a custom setting.

Comment: thank you. i have to read the camera user's manual, as i still don't get it.  any other suggestions?  btw, i have a 7D; and shutter says it can work even at a distance.

Comment: It's been long since I've used a 7D. Try to set the self-timer by pressing the drive-mode on the top-plate and rotating the rear control-dial. See if the camera responds to the remote-trigger then, aiming at the camera's grip.

Comment: @ltai, All this time I thought the IR receiver was in the camera (through the lens).  Had to give it a shot with the lens cap on to prove that spot on the front was an IR receiver.  Learn something new every day.  Thanks!

Comment: @BMitch - That would make it pretty inconvenient to hit without getting in the way. I almost always use the back one, since my camera has both.

Answer (score 0):

Again I think we need more info on the exact wireless trigger you are using. 
I have a cheapo ebay special from phottix which consists of a piece that plugs into my cameras trigger port and a wireless trigger button.

The wireless button is pretty simple, I am always running in manual mode when using this as the trigger is for sharp shots and if you care that much about sharpness.. you should be in manual and have that down pat first.

If you want to specify a shutter speed that your camera supports, you can by all means set it to that and it will fire all day at that setting. You can also set it to bulb and my specific one has a built in function, if you hold the button for 5 seconds it will then lock as on until you press it again. Allowing you to trigger for any length of time.

Comment: 'you should be in manual and have that down pat first' - manual exposure mode? or manual focus?